# How to create assets on the blockchain using the fabcar (Hyperledger Fabric) example?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

When I try to call the transaction to create a car on the ledger from the client application (changing the test script provided: query.js), the transaction returns as if there was sucess. But then, when I query the ledger, the car is not there. I tried changing the user to admin, thinking that it could be due to lack of permissions, but the result is the same.

How can I manage to create assets on the ledger, using the code in the fabcar example?

Answer (score 1):

According to your setup, you have to run invoke.js file.

Go to the code & change the following code according to your data:

```
await contract.submitTransaction('createCar', 'CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom');
```

For example, You'll add an asses of CAR20, so to add that asset you have to call corresponding chaincode method, which is 'createCar' in this scenario.

So in this case, the code will be:

```
await contract.submitTransaction('createCar', 'CAR20', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Red', 'Dinis');
```

From that invoke.js file:

```
// Submit the specified transaction.
// createCar transaction - requires 5 argument, ex: ('createCar', 'CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom')
// changeCarOwner transaction - requires 2 args , ex: ('changeCarOwner', 'CAR10', 'Dave')
await contract.submitTransaction('createCar', 'CAR12', 'Honda', 'Accord', 'Black', 'Tom');
console.log('Transaction has been submitted');
```

Comment: oh, I thought I could use the method evaluateTransaction for transactions that create assets

Comment: now I realise that I should call evaluateTransaction for queries and submitTransaction for create operations